# Find size of array without using sizeof

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I was searching for a way to find the size of an array in C without using `sizeof` and I found the following code:

```
int main ()
{
    int arr[100];
    printf ("%d\n", (&arr)[1] - arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me how is it working?

Comment: There is never a reason why you can't use `sizeof`.

Comment: It seems that the array, which has 100 elements is actually treated as item 0 of an (unnamed) array.

Comment: Nice trick, it's also standard compliant.

Comment: @effeffe: maybe, but see Daniel's comments below. I don't think it is standard compliant, although I can't think of a good reason for it not to work in practice. The subtraction, I mean -- the use of `%d` is certainly not strictly conforming and in fact would fail on a fairly normal-looking big-endian implementation with a 32 bit `int` and a 64 bit `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @SteveJessop actually you're right, it could be not standard compliant, let's follow that discussion there. However, I agree that it should work, but the standard can't let us dereference a pointer that doesn't actually point to an object or a part of it, that makes sense.

Comment: @SteveJessop The `%d` generates a warning on my compiler (clang).  Should be `%ld`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`&arr` is a pointer to an array of 100 `int`s.

The `[1]` means "add the size of the thing that is pointed to", which is an array of 100 `int`s.

So the difference between `(&arr)[1]` and `arr` is 100 `int`s.

(Note that this trick will only work in places where `sizeof` would have worked anyway.)

Comment: `[1]` doesn't mean "add the size of the thing that is pointed to". It means "add the size of the thing that is pointed to and then dereference the resultant pointer".

Answer (score 13):

`&arr` gives you a pointer to the array. `(&arr)[1]` is equivalent to `*(&arr + 1)`. `&arr + 1` gives you a pointer to the array of 100 ints that follows `arr`. Dereferencing it with `*` gives you that array that follows. Since this array is used in an additive expression (`-`), it decays to the pointer to its first element. The same happens to `arr` in the expression. So you subtract to pointers, one pointing to the non-existent element right after `arr` and the other pointing to the first element of `arr`. This gives you 100.

But it's not working. `%d` is used for `int`. Pointer difference returns you `ptrdiff_t` and not `int`. You need to use `%td` for `ptrdiff_t`. If you lie to `printf()` about the types of the parameters you're passing to it, you get well-deserved undefined behavior.

**EDIT**: `(&arr)[1]` *may* cause undefined behavior. It's not entirely clear. See the comments below, if interested.

Comment: Isn't `(&arr)[1] - arr` also undefined behaviour?

Comment: @DanielFischer C99: Additive operators: `For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.` So, it looks like this is OK. I mean the `[1]` part. And the rest is as usual.

Comment: But the last sentence in paragraph 8 of that is "If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated." And `(&arr)[1]` evaluates the `*` in `*(&arr + 1)`, if I understand correctly. It's okay if you take the address, of `(&arr)[1]`, or apply `sizeof` to it, that doesn't evaluate the `*`, but with `-`?

Comment: @DanielFischer: The standard says that `&*` is a no-op even if dereferencing would be UB (6.5.3.2/3 in C99). In the same spirit we might expect that to apply with decay-to-pointer in the place of `&`, but I think you're correct that this is not guaranteed in the standard.

Comment: @DanielFischer 6.5.3.2c4 of C99 has footnote 83 that says that `*&E` is equivalent to `E` and it reiterates the same for `&*E` as mentioned by Steve.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: my point was that although it says this for `&`, it *doesn't* say it for array decay. They are not the same thing, even though they both involve finding an address. So unless I've missed something Daniel is correct. This is UB in C99, although we might argue that's a defect in the standard.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze But we don't have `*(&E)`, we have `*(&E + 1)`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is there a difference between `&arr + 1` and `&imaginary_array_of_100_ints_following_arr`?

Comment: Would be UB to write `(int *) (&a + 1) - a`, losing some type generality but not dereferencing a pointer to a non-existent object?

Comment: @effeffe `(int*)` is unnecessary, you get this type anyway, no need to cast to it one more time.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze 6.5.3.2 (1) says "The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be [...] or an lvalue that designates an object [...]". Does `imaginary_array...` designate an object? Anyway, evaluating `*(&arr+1)` is UB, the question is whether it is evaluated here or the array-to-pointer conversion annihilates the evaluation. I don't know whether it does, hence my question.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know either what to make of it.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze `&a + 1` has type `int (*)[100]`; the conversion does not happen implicitly, the code doesn't even compile without it.

Comment: @userq `(&arr)[1]` is an array of 100 ints immediately following `arr`. In `(&arr)[1] - arr` both arrays convert to pointers to their first elements. And those are 100 elements apart.

Comment: @DanielFischer [It seems you are right in telling that `(&arr)[1]` invokes UB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32539578/3049655)

Answer (score 1):

Generally (as per visual studio), 
for an array **`&arr` is same as `arr`** ,which return the starting base address of our function.

**`(&arr)[0]` is nothing but `&arr` or `arr`**

ex: it will return some address : `1638116`

Now, `(&arr)[1]` means we are started accessing the array out of bounce means next array or next segment of the size of present array(100 ahead).

ex: it will return some address : `1638216`

Now, subtracting `(&arr)[1] - (&arr)[0]=100`

Comment: "***`(&arr)[0]` is nothing but `&arr` or `arr`***" -- `arr` and `&arr` have different types when though both point to the same location. The former is of type `int*` while the latter is of type `int(*)[100]`.

Answer (score 0):

`&variable` gives location of the variable (call it as `P`)
`&variable + 1` gives address of the location next to the variable. (call it as `N`)

`(char*)N-(char*)P` gives how many characters are there between `N` and `P`. Since each character is 1 byte sized, so the above result gives the number of bytes `P` and `N`. (which equals to the size of array in bytes).

Similarly, 
`(char*) (a+1)-(char*)a;` gives size of each element of the array in bytes.

So the number of elements in the array = `(size of array in bytes)/(size of each element in the array in bytes)`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int b = ((char*)(&a+1)-(char*)(&a));
    int c = (char*) (a+1)-(char*)a;
    b = b/c;
    printf("The size of array should be %d",b);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

int arry[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6}  //lets array elements be 6, 
so...
size in byte = (char*)(arry+6)-(char *)(arry)=24;

Comment: OP asked to explain how his example is working. You gave another example. That's not an answer to OP's question.

Answer (score -2):

```
int main ()
{
  int arr[100];
  printf ("%d\n", ((char*)(&arr+1) - (char*)(&arr))/((char*) (arr+1) -(char*) (arr)));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I'll be happy to upvote your answer if you add some explanation about how your code works. BTW, you should use `%ld`, not `%d`.