# C program address increment of array and array name

Tags: c, arrays, memory-address

```
int arr[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
printf("%p,%p\n", arr, &arr);
printf("%p,%p\n", arr+1, &arr+1);
return 0;
```

For this code, GCC compiler return

```
0xbfe41348,0xbfe41348
0xbfe4134c,0xbfe41370
```

The first line is clear, no problem. But the second line makes me confused. The first address moves to the next `int`, so it is 4 bytes after `arr`, clear. However, for **`&arr+1`** I thought it will point to the end of the whole array `arr[10]`, so it should add **4*10** to the address. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019009/find-size-of-array-without-using-sizeof-in-c, it should explain it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you think is right and it is done that way only.

Since `&arr` => `0xbfe41348` and

`0xbfe41348` + `0x28`(`4*10` in decimal) = `0xbfe41370`

I think you got confused due to addition of decimal to a hexadecimal number.

Comment: oh my god, I forgot it was hexa ... what a stupid mistake! thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 6):

The type of `&arr` is 'pointer to array of 10 `int`'.  Therefore, when you add one to it (`&arr+1`), it moves to the start of the next array of 10 `int`, which is 40 bytes beyond the start of `&arr`.

Comment: I don't understand why an answer like this (that adds nothing, just a re-wording what's already inside the question body) would get so many upvotes. Does some people on Stack Overflow have a fan-base following them, praising them with upvotes for whatever they write?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Those re-wordings can be some times be oooohhhh!!! (i get it now) Factor....:)

Comment: @MudassirHussain Definitely not in this case, *web rocker* already explicitly states that he/she would expect to have 40 added to the address. Probably just never for any case where the guy who asks uses his own genuine words; a re-wording could be useful only maybe when the guy who asks uses a quoted explanation that he's yet to correctly understand, which is not the case here, there aren't any quoted explanations here.

Answer (score 2):

`&arr+1` does, in fact, add `40` to the base address of the array `arr` but it's not *obvious* since the addresses are in hexadecimal or base 16, not decimal.

Now, for what it's worth, I'll add some explanation of each statement to make things clear.

```
int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

The above statement defines `arr` to be of type `int[10]`, i.e., an array of `10` integers. It then initializes `arr` with an array initializer list.

```
printf("%p,%p\n", arr, &arr);
```

In the above statement `arr` decays (evaluates or implicitly converted) to a pointer to its first element. Therefore its type is `int *`. `&arr` evaluates to a pointer to `arr`. Type of `arr` is `int[10]`. Therefore, type of `&arr` is `int (*)[10]`, i.e., a pointer to an array of 10 integers. Parentheses are used because array subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than `*` operator. So without parentheses `int *[10]` means an array of 10 pointers to integers. This is one of the cases where an array does not decay into a pointer to its first element.

Please note that both `arr` and `&arr` evaluate to the same value, i.e., the base address of the array in the above `printf` statement but their types are different and they have different pointer arithmetic. This shows up in the following statement -

```
printf("%p,%p\n", arr+1, &arr+1);
```

`arr+1` points to the next element. Here element type is `int`. Therefore `arr+1` evaluates to

```
arr + (1 * sizeof(int))
```

`&arr + 1` also points to the next element but here the element type is `int[10]` - an array of 10 `integers`. Therefore `&arr + 1` evaluates to

```
arr + (1 * sizeof(int[10]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, I'm much clearer now. Since I made a mistake about the data format, and the accepted answer point it  out, I chose that. But still thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr+1
```

Here arr is base pointer to integer array so results in incremented by `sizeof(int)`

```
&arr+1
```

Here `&arr` results in address of array so result is incremented by array size.