# Assigning Address of String Literal to a pointer

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any difference in assigning the address of string literal to a character pointer?

```
char *ptr = &"Hello";
printf("%s",ptr);
```

When I printed, it printed "Hello" correctly.
Is this similar to assigning address of array to a pointer? Is there any use of assigning address this way? What does &"Hello" returns? Constant pointer to a character?

```
char a[]="Hi";
char *ptr2 = &a;
```

Also &a+1 will print the address that is just outside of array boundary. However we cannot use this to get the size of an array it looks. I tried to print array contents something like below, but it just prints one character.

```
for(i=0;i<((&a+1)-&a);i++)  printf("%c",*ptr2++);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *ptr = &"Hello";
```

Your compiler should have warned you about this. `"Hello"` is of type `char[6]` (the length of the string plus 1 for the terminating `'\0'` null character). So `&"Hello"` is of type `char (*)[6]`, or pointer to array of 6 `char`s. There is no implicit conversion from that type to `char*`.

If you want a pointer to the string, drop the `&`:

```
const char *ptr = "Hello";
```

This takes advantage of the rule that an expression of array type (such as `"Hello"` is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element. (This conversion isn't done if the array is the operand of a unary `&` or `sizeof` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array object.)

(I've added the `const` because it's safer; you can't legally modify the contents of a string literal, and the `const` reminds the compiler not to let you try. Thanks to Bathsheba for reminding me.) (Actually modifying the contents has undefined behavior. Long story.)

You'll note that `ptr` points to the first character of the string, not to the entire string. That's (probably) exactly what you want. In C, an array is usually manipulated via a pointer to its elements, not via a pointer to the entire array. Pointer arithmetic is used to traverse the array and access all its elements.

It's important to keep in mind that constructing a pointer to an array's initial element does not remember the array's size. You have to keep track of that yourself. If the array contains a string, you'll generally look for the terminating `'\0'`, or use a function that does so. For other arrays, it's common to store the length separately. For example a function might take two arguments, the address of an array's initial element and an integer (`size_t`) holding the number of elements.

Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Plus one although I'd much rather see `const char *ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *ptr = &"Hello";
```

This is not valid . Compiler will issue a warning .

Type of `"Hello"` is `char[6]` and type of `&"Hello"` is `char(*)[6]` . Declare and initialize `ptr` like this -

```
char (*ptr)[6] = &"Hello";     // ptr is pointer to array of char of size 6
```

In `for` loop , your condition -

```
i<((&a+1)-&a);   // it should be i<(*(&a+1)-a);
```

But **don't do this** as it invokes ***undefined behaviour***.

[To know more about it refer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537471/is-array-1-1-safe-to-use-to-get-the-last-element-of-an-automatic/32537682#32537682)

Comment: Noticed that compiler warning was disabled. Now I am getting the warning atleast.

Comment: @JonWheelock Well ,you should always enable compiler warning :)

Comment: Also just for curiosity, how do I print the address (&a)+1 instead of &a+1? If I put parenthesis, it still prints the address value beyond the array boundary.  For example in the code below, I want the last print statement to display 0028FF05 and not 0028FF10. Is adding constant to (ptr*)[] is not allowed?
char a[] = "Hello World";
 char (*ptrToEntireArray)[] = &a;
  printf("&ptrToEntireArray = %p\n",&a);
  printf("&ptrToEntireArray+1 = %p\n",(&a)+1);
Results:
&ptrToEntireArray = 0028FF04
&ptrToEntireArray+1 = 0028FF10

Comment: @JonWheelock Printing address beyond boundary is not a problem , but trying to read/ write will have undefined behaviour . So ,printing that address should not be any problem I think .

Comment: My question is: If printf ("%p",&a) prints 0028FF04, how can I print the address 0028FF05? Adding 1 will  add size of entire array to the first address. I want to print the absolute address  0028FF05 using &a. Note that this is just for curiosity and not for using it in coding. Also is there any use of &a?

Comment: @JonWheelock Make as pointer `p` point to `&a`and while printing print address of `p+1` . See here -https://ideone.com/PyagZG

Comment: I think I got the answer. It should be *(&a)+1 and prints correctly. But still not clear why (&a) +1  prints the address of (0028FF04 + size of entire array) even though there is a parenthesis. So inside printf, pointer arithmetic work differently!!

Comment: @JonWheelock `*(&a)` is just `a` .  And your expression evaulates to `a+1`. Just similar to mine . `&a` will create a pointer to array , thats why it does not work as expected .

Comment: Splitting works and I had tried. I was just trying to print without assigning &a to another pointer.

Comment: @JonWheelock Yes , both of them are similar (but not excatly same ). If you wan to clarify on `a` , `&a` , `&a[0]` , read here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361111/are-a-a-a-a0-a0-and-a00-identical-pointers