# Length of an array

Tags: c, arrays

I need to find the length of an array, how would I do this without using the `sizeof` function.

eg if

```
Array 1 = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

the size of this array would be `7`.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function, it's a Operator.

Comment: That is not C syntax.

Comment: http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-size-of-structure-without-sizeof/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019009/find-size-of-array-without-using-sizeof-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many high-level programming language save the length of an array once it is created.

```
/* e.g. Java */
int[] foo = new int[10];
assert(foo.length == 10);
```

But the length of an array is not saved in C! This is useful as you can decide how you want to save the length with respect to optimization. You basically have three possibilities to get/save the length:

mark the end of the array with a certain value (i.e. \0 is used for strings)

```
char foo[] = "bar";
/* foo has length 4(sic!) as '\0' is automatically added to the end*/
int i = 0;
while(foo[i] != '\0'){
    printf("%c",foo[i]);
    i++;
}
```

save the length of the array in a variable

```
int foo[] = {1,2,3,4};
int length = 4;    
for(int i = 0; i < length;i++){
    printf("%i, ",foo[i]);
}
```

use sizeof (warning: sizeof is (mostly) computed at compile time and its use is restricted. you can only use sizeof within the function where the array has been created. when you pass an array to a function you only pass the pointer to the first element. therefore you can loop through this array as you know what offset must be used(type of its elements), but you do not know how big it is unless you also passed the length or added a sentinel value)

```
/* ok */
int foo[] = {1,2,3,4};
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(foo)/sizeof(int);i++){
    printf("%i, ",foo[i]);
}

/* not ok */
void foo(int bar[]);
void foo(int bar[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(bar)/sizeof(int);i++){
        printf("%i, ",bar[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    foo(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use `sizeof` (tell us why, please), you can use a loop and a sentinel (-1 or some number that can not be used in the array):

```
int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1};
int count = 0;

while (arr[count] != -1) count++;
```

Comment: I would have used the condition `!= -1`.

Comment: It's just that I had to write a small piece of code(function) without using builtin functions other than the ones from stdio.h

Comment: @PeterSand `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. In case that makes a difference to your problem.

Comment: `int a[10]; int *fun(int *a) {return a; } printf("%d",sizeof(fun(a)));` This would print `4` not `40`. Maybe OP has a case like this

Comment: @ameyCU, are you sure?, `&Array_1[1] - Array_1` is always `1` for me

Comment: @AlterMann  You missed bracket . Its `(&Array_1)[1]` not `&Array_1[1]` .That will make difference.

Comment: @ameyCU, Oooh, I get you, but then you need a 2D array, isn't it?

Comment: @AlterMann  Its not address of second item . That first expression will be evaluated to this `*(&Array_1 +1)` . No , we don't need 2-d array.

Comment: @ameyCU ...which contradicts [what you've said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32537682/3049655)

Comment: @CoolGuy  But it wasn't done that if it evaluated or not . I think it was not completely discussed. Thanks for pointing it out . My bad i withdraw  my previous comment.

Comment: @ameyCU, yes, as pointed out by CoolGuy and yourself, if the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

Comment: @AlterMann Ohh  my mistake , that was not a good thing to point to HIM, I would withdraw my previous comment.