# C getting the size of an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

the code:

```c
int arr[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

printf("%lu %lu\n", *(&arr + 1), arr); // 6422036 6422016
printf("%lu\n", *(&arr + 1) - arr);    // 5
```

Why the second `printf` prints 5 instead of 20?

Comment: `&arr` has type *pointer-to-array* `int [5]` so `*(&arr + 1)` is the address of the first element in the next `5 int` array after `arr` and the type you are printing is `int *` so the values are `5 int` (20-bytes) away from each other. (and technically you invoke *Undefined Behavior* due to the mismatch in *conversion specifier* and type. `"%p"` is the proper specifier for pointers (though `"%lu"` should be sufficiently wide))

Comment: This is just a suggestion, you might want to edit this and change the title to a question. It's a bit vague.

Comment: Good call, but to what? *"C - Why the difference when printing Array Addresses"*?

Comment: Because the distance between `*(&arr + 1)` and `arr` is **5 elements**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this piece of code determine array size without using sizeof( )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154380/how-does-this-piece-of-code-determine-array-size-without-using-sizeof)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It is also UB because of this: C11, 6.5.6/9: "*If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.*"

Comment: Ooh good point....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points in your interesting question :

1. How does operation on pointers work ?
2. What is the difference between arr and &arr ?

**1 : How does operation on pointers work ?**

Try the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int simpleInt= 10 ;
printf("Output 1 : %p %p \n", &simpleInt+1, &simpleInt); // 61FE20 and 61FE1C
printf("Output 2 : %lld \n", &simpleInt+1 - &simpleInt); // 1
printf("Output 3 : %lld\n", (uint64_t)(&simpleInt+1) - (uint64_t)(&simpleInt)); // 4

}
```

Output 1 : Clearly, the difference between the two printed pointer values is 4

Output 2 : You are performing operation on `int *`. 1 is added to an operand of type `int *` and after an operand of type `int *` is substracted. From an " `int *` point of view" (if I could simplify it like that), only one is added. So, the output is 1.

Ouput 3 : Each operands of the substraction are casted to a long long unsigned int. So the substraction is done on integers and not on pointers. The ouput is 4, as expected.

**2. What is the difference between arr and &arr ?**

Let's have a look to the following code

```
int arr[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

printf("Output 1 : %p %p %p \n", arr, &arr, *(&arr) ); //Seems to be the same thing but NOT. int*, int*[5], int*, respectively

// printf("%lld\n", arr - &arr ); // compilation error : int * and int(*)[5]
printf("Output 2 : %lld\n", arr - *(&arr) );
//printf("%lld\n", &arr - *(&arr) ); // compilation error : int(*)[5] and int *


printf("Output 3 : %p %p %p \n", (arr + 1), (&arr + 1), *(&arr + 1) ); // +4, +20, +20
printf("Output 4 : %lld\n", *(&arr + 1) - arr);

printf("Output 5 : %lld\n", (uint64_t)(*(&arr + 1)) - (uint64_t)(arr));
```

Ouput 1 : The value are the same but not the type of arguments. And this point is very important. The name of an array is a pointer to its first element. In your case, your array is an array of `int`, so `arr` is a pointer to int : `int*`. `&arr` is the address of your variable `arr` which is an array of 5 integers. So the type of `&arr` is `int(*)[5]`. And the type of `*(&arr)` is `int*`

Output 2 : Some lines give compilation errors because of the explanation above. And you could do operations on the same pointer type : `arr` and `*(&arr)`

Output 3 : Depending which kind of pointer is incremented, +4 or +20 is obtained. +20 because 1 is added to an operand of type `int(*)[5]` : 5 * 4 (sizeof `int` = 4)

Output 4 & 5 : As, in the first point (operation on pointer), your are performing a substraction with `int*` as operand

Answer (score 0):

> Why the second printf prints 5 instead of 20?

Code is living on the edge.

`&arr` is the address of the array, so `+ 1` is the address of the *next* array: 5 `int` later.  So far, this is good.

`*(&arr + 1)` de-references that address. So we get that *next* array.  Not so good [@RobertS supports Monica Cellio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168278/c-getting-the-size-of-an-array/61169705#comment108211142_61168278). An array passed to a ... function like `printf()` is converted to the address of the first element, an `int *`.

`*(&arr + 1) - arr` subtracts two pointers of the same type `int *` that are 5 `int` apart leading to difference of `5` of type `intptr_t`.  Recall that pointer subtraction is the difference of the number of  the referenced types (`int` in this case), not the difference of the pointer values.  **5 not 20**.

Code attempts to print a `intptr_t` as an `unsigned long` with `"%lu"`, which might work, might not (UB).  Not so good.   Better to use `"%td"`.

```
printf("%td\n", *(&arr + 1) - arr);
```